# Select only arrays for foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've got a foreach statement that on an item that has both objects and arrays in it.

```
foreach($result as $data)
```

that contains both arrays and objects. how do i specify the foreach to only select to loop through one or the other? when it loops through them all it takes forever

I had tried `foreach($result->data as $data)` but then it errors on the arrays telling me it is trying to get property of an object, which is understandable. once I add an `if` statement to check if the first result is an object it almost triples the script run time since there are so many results.

Comment: can you store the objects and arrays differently in the main array? something like array('arrays' => (), 'objects' => ()); otherwise you have to process all of them and filter out the ones you don't want

Comment: you could look at array_filter() but it still iterates over the whole array...

Comment: it's a result from an api call, unfortunately I have no control over it.
i'll try array_filter, that may be a little faster. what's weird is if i let it run as foreach($result->data as $data) even though it's yelling about the trying to get a property of an obj, it's still much faster. we're talking about 10-15 sec faster easy.

Comment: You mind showing what the data looks like?

Comment: `var_dump($result);` and post it here :-)

Comment: sure. this is a small chunk of the foreach. once the array hits 10 entries, it starts over - pagination.
[pastbin paste](http://pastebin.com/4M0PpRxE)

Comment: Surely you'd do the whole `foreach($data as $item) { /*code here*/ }` and run a few if statements using [`is_object()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) or [`is_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) then iterate accordingly?

Comment: pastebin won't let me post the full thing because it's too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just use [is_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) and [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) (both return a boolean):

```
if (is_object($var)) {
    // do something
} else if (is_array($var)) {
    // well then, do something else
}
```

Comment: I tried to mark @Darren as the answer since he said it first but this was spot on. Thanks, I had no idea this existed.

Comment: EDIT: still slow but atleast it's valid